# python regexp remove last numbers from string

Tags: python

How can I remove the last digits from a string using python regexp or similar:
I have an IP-address `10.121.100.200` and would want to only display `10.121.100.` leaving out the last numbers.

Comment: all digits after the last `.` ?

Comment: Do you need the tailing `.` at the end, or is that just a full stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> v = '10.121.100.200'
>>> ".".join(v.split('.')[0:-1])
'10.121.100'
```

If you want to leave the last little dot at the end, then:

```
>>> ".".join(v.split('.')[0:-1]) + '.'
'10.121.100.'
```

Just refactor it to a function, and you're good to go.

Comment: he wants a point at the end. You should add this but nice solution at all

Comment: @Dlotan Are you sure thats not just a full stop?

Comment: hmm could be possible but idk.

Answer (score 10):

Regex:

```
re.sub(r'\d+$', '', ip)
```

Without regexes

```
''.join(ip.rpartition('.')[:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version

```
'{}.'.format('10.121.100.200'.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
'10.121.100.'
```